# Unable to bridge network on Windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

I am unable to bridge network connections due to "unauthorized access privileges"; however, I am an Admin on this comp. First I thought the issue might be because my account was created via my company domain, and even though I had Admin rights, maybe because of how the admin account was set up, I didn't. So I tried to log in as `Administrator` which was created locally, but when I was in that account, I didn't even have the option to bridge the networks. I have tried to sign in as other users, but they don't work either.

Can anyone suggest something else to try, or tell me why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Run explorer as the Administrator account:

Type the following in command prompt

```
runas /user:domain\Administrator "explorer.exe"
```

It will then prompt for a password, enter it and hit return. You will now see a window explorer window, go to the networking within that and you should now be able to bridge connections.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work :(